# Content in div blocks disapear in mobile?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

In my site http://www.xn--ntcasinon-v2a.eu/ I used `@media` codes below to remove some of the content in mobile and it works fine but I am trying to do the exact same thing with the same code in http://www.nya-casino.com/ and the content disappears in mobile. Anyone know what code in the theme causes this?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 780px)  {.info{display:none;}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 780px)  {.benefits{display:none;}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 780px)  {.site-title{width:70%;}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 780px)  {.logo img{max-height:65px;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `class="hidden-xs"` to all those divs inside the `.item` divs. That class has this rule which makes the content invisible:

```
.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Since this is a general bootstrap rule (which you probably shouldn't change), you should erase that class from the divs.

Comment: Thank you verry much removing the class worked. Strange it works on the first site with the hidden-xs class.

Answer (score 0):

The `only` sometimes are ignored by some web browsers, so the code would be like this->

`@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 780px)  {.info{display:none;}}`

As you see there isn't the word "only".